# How do i solve this ('.NETFramework,Version=v4.8) problem?

Tags: asp.net-core, dll, console

```
using System;
using Mathematik; //I can't add this library

namespace BeispielCsharp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
        }
    }
}
```

//Mathematik

```
using System;

namespace Mathematik
{
    public class Operation
    {
        public string publicDaten { get; set; } 
        private string privateDaten { get; set; }
        internal string internalDaten { get; set; }

        private void samlung()
        {

        }
    }
    public class samlung
    {
        private void berechnung()
        {
            Operation i = new Operation();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Project '..\Mathematik\Mathematik.csproj' targets 'net6.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'. BeispielCsharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two projects are different frameworks, So You can't have one refer to the other. As `Denis` said, you have two options，I perfer to recommend you to migrate BeispielCsharp  from .net Framework to .net core 6.0. Here are [links1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/327581/how-to-migrate-net-framework-to-net-core-applicati.html),[links2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you for your comment But I don't know which package to install There are many packages. and I couldn't find the 4.8 package on nuget

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) about how to upgrade your .NET Framework to  .NET 6

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the C# application to the console application. The example in the video is given via Winform.

Answer (score 0):

Your BeispielCsharp is version .net framework 4.8 and your Mathematik is of version 6.0. And you cannot use libraries that are on different framework version. So you have 2 options either update the BeispielCsharp to version 6 or downgrade the Mathematik to version 4.8.

You can see the .net version of the project by checking the .csproj. The .csproj is in your respected project folder

Answer (score 0):

My BeispielCsharp is .net framework version 4.8 and my Mathematik is version 6.0. And I was not able to use libraries with different framework version. So when I upgraded both projects to the same version, there was no problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32508980)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the target framework of the BeispielCSharp project to **.NET 6.0**. You can follow these steps for this:
Right-click on the BeispielCsharp project in Solution Explorer and click on "Properties".
In the window that opens, go to the **"Application"** tab.
In the Target Framework section, select .NET 6.0.
Click "Apply" and "OK" buttons.